# SSIS:Convert INT to GUID?

Tags: types, ssis, type-conversion, expression

I am having massive Trouble trying to convert an Int datatype i get from a SharePoint list into a GUID datatype.
here is the Scenario:

[image: Scenario]

now when i get to the external data which is being gotten from the SP List, i am able to Change the value for the ID to a GUID but as soon as i get to the internal data, and want tu Change the datatype there too, i get the following error message (note, Error message is partialy in german, not translated since the error is quite clear in it self, can't convert into int)

[image: Error message]

is there a way around all this, or does anybody have any ideas as to how someone could convert an ID into a GUID
I have already tried the following, but all i get is red letters indicating the Expression is written catastrophically wrong: `(DT_GUID)SP_ID`
(done using the Expression Transformation, but as mentioned failed to convert or even work at all)

Thanks to you all in advance, looking Forward to your great Support!

Answer (score 0):

A guid data type contains alpha numeric data, which is the reason it will not convert to an INT [article about GUID data type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx).  If the table you are populating is in in a SQL server then the data type for the field should be set to 'uniqueidentifier'

Comment: I AM TRYING TO GO FROM INT --To--> GUID !
not the other way around

Comment: Sorry mis-read the question. To the best of my knowledge it is not possible to convert and INT to a GUID.  You could try generating a new GUID see - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx
?
Why do you wish to convert an INT value to a GUID?  Just trying to understand why so see if l can make any other suggestions